# In what sense do the real and complex places correspond to setting q equal to 1 or -1?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, arithmetic-geometry, motives, euler-characteristics, field-with-one-element

It often happens that if we have a scheme $X/\mathbb Z$ (or an open subset thereof) and we denote by $p(q) = X(\mathbb F_q)$, then $p(1)$ and $p(-1)$ compute the euler characteristic of $X(\mathbb C)$ and $X(\mathbb R)$ respectively. For instance, for $X = \mathbb P^n$, $p(q) = 1+q+\dots+q^n$, $p(1) = n+1$ and $p(-1) = 1$ or $0$ depending on wether $n$ is even or odd, both of which are correct. This works more generally for things paved by affines but in general, it might not even make sense to "plug in $q=1,-1$" since $p(q)$ might not be a polynomial in $q$.

John Baez provides one possible explanation of this phenomenon [here](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/counting/counting.pdf) as part of a more general, speculative story. I would like to ask for other possible explanations of this phenomenon, especially from a $\mathbb F_1$ point of view. Does our current state of "knowledge" about what $\mathbb F_1$ is provide any insight into why the above phenomenon should work or when exactly we expect such things to work?

In another direction, does the motivic point of view have anything to say about this? For instance, is there a relation between the Hodge structures of the cohomology of $X(\mathbb R)$ and $X(\mathbb C)$ and the weights in the cohomology of $X/\mathbb F_q$, at least in nice cases?

Comment: [Scholze's Rio talk](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Rio.pdf) seems related (look at the section of shtukas over integers).

Comment: I suspect that you observation only concerns cellular schemes (or those that are "of mixed Tate type" in a certain sense). It does not work (even) for elliptic curves.

Comment: On the other hand, your claim is easy for cellular varieties.

Comment: @MikhailBondarko You are right that it does not work a priori for elliptic curves but unless I made a mistake, the following reasonable procedure seems to give the right answer. For $X$ an elliptic curve, $X(\mathbb F_p) = p+1-a_p$ where $a_p $ is the trace of the Frobenius at $p$ on the Tate module. To figure out $a_{-1}$, it seems reasonable to take the trace of complex conjugation which if I computed it correctly is $0$. Therefore, this would suggest that the Euler characteristic of the elliptic curve over $\mathbb R$ is $-1+1 - 0 = 0$ which indeed seems to be correct.

Comment: @MikhailBondarko Even more, if we consider the same elliptic curve over $\mathbb C$, then we should probably look at the trace of the square of complex conjugation which I think has eigenvalues $(-1)^2,1^2  = 1,1$ and so $p(1) "=" 1+1 - 2 = 0$ which is also correct!

Comment: The Lefschetz number of a map is the Euler characteristic of the fixed set, so maybe the question is: in what say do $q=\pm1$ correspond to the identity and complex conjugation? If the Galois action on $H_\ell(X)$ factors through $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}^{ab}/\mathbb{Q})=\hat{\mathbb{Z}}^\times$, then we should he happy since $-1\in\hat{\mathbb{Z}}^\times$ is complex conjugation and $1\in \hat{\mathbb{Z}}^\times$ is the identity. I'm not sure what happens in the non-abelian case. What happens if $X$ is the spectrum of the ring of integers of a non-abelian number field?